# Opencart 2 API session issues

Tags: php, api, session, curl, opencart

I'm trying to use the OpenCart 2 API but I'm not entirely familiar with it, nor Opencart in general TBH.

I have created an API key in the admin area, and I can successfully communicate with the API from an external source by passing the username, password and API key itself, and I get a success message.

Example:

```
$url = "http://opencart.local:8888/index.php?route=api/login";
$postData = array(
        "username" => $username,
        "password" => $password,
        "key" => $key
    );

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));

$response = curl_exec($handle);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$response = substr($response, $header_size);

curl_close($handle);

$return = json_decode($response, true);
```

The return response is as follows:

> array(2) {   ["success"]=>   string(42) "Success: API session
>   successfully started!"   ["token"]=>   string(32)
>   "rfjOIzMWobWSvKvdy2LnWsekp9v1qoQQ" }

Then, after that, I call the cart/add function in the API, to add a product (by ID) to the cart:

```
$url = "http://opencart.local:8888/index.php?route=api/cart/add";
$cartData = array(
        "product_id" => '47',
        "quantity" => '1'
    );
```

which I CURL in the same way, but the response I get from OpenCart is:

> array(1) {   ["error"]=>   array(1) {
>       ["warning"]=>
>       string(54) "Warning: You do not have permission to access the API!"   } }

When I check the problem, it seems that the api_id which is required by opencart in order to grant permission is missing:

```
$this->session->data['api_id']
```

even though this is set when logging in through the API. It's somehow losing this session data when I do the second call to add a product to the cart. Bearing in mind that when this launches live, I will have no access to the OpenCart code as this is an external CRM which will only be able to communicate via the API with only the username, password and API Key.

Any ideas? I would appreciate any help as I'm a noob to OpenCart!

Thank you

Comment: go to: `Admin CP > System > Users > User Groups > Administrator [edit] > Select all Access and Permissions and click save.`

Comment: I appreciate that this may be a solution for my development, but ultimately I will have no control over the OpenCart installation as what I'm creating is a third party CRM which hooks up to OpenCart, and if possible I'd prefer to use the default settings as most clients will probably not be comfortable doing this.

Comment: Actually, all the permissions are selected as default....

Comment: Then you must have to `configure API` in OC Admin panel. Without any configuration you can't access API anymore.

Comment: Do you have admin panel access?

Comment: Check this link for same issue : https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=134336

Comment: @hardiksolanki Yes I have full access to admin

Comment: @MichaelEmerson I have the same issue, how do you resolved it?

Comment: @hardiksolanki Unfortunately yet to be resolved - but this project has been put on the back burner so not pursued it any further yet, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience; I accidentally deleted the API key and created a new one, but the API just stopped working.

I found out that `$this->config->get('config_api_id');` always returns '1'. So changed my newly created API key `api_id` value to 1 on the database and it worked.

I am using Version 2.1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a file for the cookies, in the curl options. Almost all authenticaions need it to write and read: curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie_file.txt');